# Does the deezer api request quota applies by URL or Oauth token?

Tags: api, oauth, deezer

this is basically my question, do you know if the deezer api request quota applies by URL or Oauth token ? I mean if a same server make requests for 5 different deezer users at the same time, is the quota 50/5 seconds (so applies by URL) or 250/5 seconds (so applies by token).

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The quota limit is by IP address, so if you execute the request from a server, the limit will be 50 for 5 seconds.